# Add static block into "home" category from backend

Tags: magento-1, backend, static-block, cms-block

I saw that in possible add a static block from the category management into Magento backend as you can see in picture

[image: Screen]

I tried to add the static block and to display it but it doesn't work.

I want to display a different static block for each categories that I have (e.g. for the category 1 I want display a gallery with only pictures that are about the specific category also a little banner that have a specific content for the specific category, and so for every category)

How can I fix it? I prefer to manage it from the backend

**EDIT:**

at left is the screenshot from my magento's backend

at right  is my webiste category after saving the configuration.
[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

Please check you display mode must be products and static block in display after that select static block you want to display.

Comment: thank you so much... I did it before, but it doesn't work... If I try to open that category it doesn't show nothing.... how can I fix it?

Comment: Hi, do you have news about this question? Right now I've again the same problem... Do you can help me to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

You have pointed correct location in example image.

- You need to create a different CMS static block for each category, for which you want to show static block content.
- Then click on individual category, click on **Display Settings** tab.
- Select **Static block only** or **Static block and products** for **Display Mode**.
- Now select respective static block from drop down CMS Block.
- Click on Save button.

Comment: thank you so much... I did it before, but it doesn't work... If I try to open that category it doesn't show nothing.... how can I fix it?

Comment: Hi, do you have news about this question? Right now I've again the same problem... Do you can help me to fix it?

Comment: What problem are you facing while following above process?

Comment: I did all, but if I try to open my website I don't see the static block that I choosed to show

Comment: Please check whether static block which you are choosing is enabled and is selected for right store view.

Comment: I checked.... the static block is enabled, also the store view is correct..

Answer (score 0):

What you have shown in your image is correct, then follow these steps:

1. Create a static block you want to show in your category page.
2. Go to the category as shown in your image above
3. Choose the correct static block for your category as shown below. Remember to choose "Static Block and Products" for Display Mode to have a static block and products.
   [image]
4. Save this category
5. Go to the next category and chose the next block and so on.

Comment: thank you so much... I did it before, but it doesn't work... If I try to open that category it doesn't show nothing.... how can I fix it?

Comment: If you do the above steps and save the category you say nothing shows up?

Comment: exactly!  I choosed  a static block and displayed it as your raccomandation, but if I try to open the specific category I don't see the static block that i choose... the category is displayed normally...  I don't know why...

Comment: Can you post a screenshot where you have the setting like i showed above?

Comment: Hi, do you have news about this question? Right now I've again the same problem... Do you can help me to fix it?

Comment: Did you do the steps i said and can you post a screeshot?

Comment: Yes I did... But the satitc block does not displayed into my category page... I set display mode as static block and products, also I choosed the static block that I want to show... I saved the configuration... So i opened my website, I got to the selected category but I don't see he static block... If you can wait half an hour that I come back to my office I will post a screenshot about it...

Comment: I added a screen in the main post... I'm waiting your reply

Comment: Do you have a test environment where you can show the block hints ?

Comment: What do you mean with "block hints"?

Comment: http://insync.co.in/how-to-enable-template-path-and-block-name-hints-in-magento-commerce/